# match merge for repeated measures in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I haven't been having much luck with this so I can hopefully get some help (I feel like there's an easy answer out there but don't seem to have landed on it)

I have multiple rows per ID number (160 per person based on trials of a cognitive task) and I want to keep all of the rows but attach a new column to the end of my dataset that will be the same for every participant which I have matched per subject ID

```
 subj_index Block   subj_index  SUIPRONE
    1        C1        1          1
    1        C1        2          3
    2        C2     
    2        C2
```

I just want to append a column to the first two columns that matches subject index and if that match is true, insert value of suiprone. I just need to scale this up over thousands of rows. Any suggestions?

```
subj_index  Block   SUIPRONE
        1        C1    1
        1        C1    1    
        2        C2    3
        2        C2    3
```

Comment: "I just want to append a column to the first two columns that matches subject index and if that match is true"  Matches subject index to *what*?  Please give some sample data and an example of the output that you would expect.

Comment: Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: I've tried some variants of vlookup and hlookup but haven't found much success. So in the first example I have two columns with subj_index, I want those to match (only in the first column there will be multiple rows and the the third column each will only be there once) then when they do I just want an unchanging value (suiprone) to get thrown in a new column (like in second example, but scaled up). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `subj_index`, `Block`, `subj_index`, and `SUIPRONE` are columns A, B, C, and D, respectively, the I believe you are looking for the following in `E2`:

`=IF(A2=C2,D2,"")`

Then just drag down using the box in the lower-right corner.

Comment: this only works on the first row bc in columns C and D scores and subj_index doesn't repeat, that's been my issues that I have one repeating column and one that doesn't and want to match these two columns

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't repeat"?  Every value is unique?  Or that there are blanks, and that you are trying to match against the most recent value seen in the rows above?  Or something else entirely?